# Gaussian Integral

Tags: integration

Consider the following Gaussian Integral $$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \ dx$$

The usual trick to calculate this is to consider $$I^2 = \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \ dx \right) \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^{2}} \ dy \right)$$

and convert to polar coordinates. We get $\sqrt{\pi}$ as the answer.

Is it possible to get the same answer by considering $I^{3}, I^{4}, \dots, I^{n}$?

Answer (score 17):

Define 
$$
I_n = \prod_{i=1}^n \int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-x_i^2}\,dx_i = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{-|x|^2}\,dx,
$$
where $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $|x| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}$.

By [spherical coordinate integration transform in $\mathbb{R}^n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coarea_formula#Applications):

$$
I_n  = \int_0^\infty\left\{\int_{\partial B(0,r)} e^{-|x|^2}\,dS\right\}\,dr.
$$
For $e^{-|x|^2} = e^{-r^2}$ on $\partial B(0,r)$ which is a constant when the radius is fixed, hence above integral reads:
$$
I_n = \int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}\left\{\int_{\partial B(0,r)} 1\,dS\right\}\,dr.
$$
Now
$$
\int_{\partial B(0,r)} 1\,dS = |\partial B(0,r)|= \omega_n r^{n-1},
$$
which is the surface area of the $(n-1)$-sphere with radius $r$, and $\omega_n$ is the surface area of the unit $(n-1)$-sphere:
$$
\omega_n = \frac{n\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma\left(1+\frac{n}{2}\right)},
$$
notice this can be computed by a recursive relation or taking derivative of the volume element of the $n$-ball.

Hence
$$
 I_n = \omega_n\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}r^{n-1}\,dr = \frac{1}{2}\omega_n \Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) .
$$

Now by Gamma function's property (proved by integration by parts):
$$
\Gamma\left(1+\frac{n}{2}\right) = \frac{n}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right).
$$
There goes your desired result:
$$
I_n = \pi^{n/2}.
$$

Comment: While this is very nice, it feels a bit like cheating by assuming you know the gamma function. This especially since $\Gamma(1/2)$ is computed using the error function.

Answer (score 0):

For three dimensions (if I figure out higher dimensions I will edit), one could try a similar argument by using spherical coordinates. If you can perform the integral, $$\int_0^\infty r^2 e^{-r^2} dr$$, then we can compute the desired integral. But [This question addresses this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66084/how-to-solve-this-integral-int-infty-infty-x2-e-x2-mathrm-dx). For this you need the spherical change of co-ordinates see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Integration_and_differentiation_in_spherical_coordinates). You simply mimic the proof for the two dimensional case. I will leave the work to you.

**Edit** It seems in higher dimensions if one knows how to compute the integral, 
$$\int_0^\infty r^{n-1} e^{-r^2} dr$$ then we can compute the integral in *essentially the same way*. To see this you need higher dimensional spherical co-ordinates. For this see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersphere#Spherical_volume_element).