# Find the value of the integral $I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^\frac{-y^2}{2}~dy$ .

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^\frac{-y^2}{2}~dy$$

Let $\dfrac{y^2}{2}=z$ ,

$y~dy=dz$

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-z}}{\sqrt{2z}}dz$$

Comment: This is a popular integral and has likely been answered on this board before. The solution is also on youtube. edit:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429632/gaussian-integral

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral

Comment: multiply your integral for $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ and then use two coordinate transformation

Comment: See also http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqNzKeVCYBU :)

Answer (score 5):

Let $x^2 = y^2/2$, so $\mathrm{d}y = \sqrt{2}\,\mathrm{d}x$
then 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2/2} \mathrm{d}y = 
\sqrt{2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \mathrm{d}x
$$
Can you recognize the last integral as the [Gaussian Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) ?

Answer (score 4):

$$I^2=\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-x^2/2}dx\cdot \int_{\mathbb R}e^{-y^2/2}dy=\int_{\mathbb R^2}e^{(-x^2-y^2)/2}dxdy=\\ 
=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\{x^2+y^2\leq n^2\}}e^{(-x^2-y^2)/2}dxdy=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^ne^{-r^2/2}rdrd\varphi=\\
=2\pi\lim_{n\to+\infty}(-e^{-n^2/2}+e^0)=2\pi.$$ Hence $I=\sqrt{2\pi}.$

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you know something about distributions then you'll see that $\exp(-y^2/2)/\sqrt{2\pi}$ is the density of the normal distribution which integrates to one, so your answer is $\sqrt{2\pi}$.