# Evaluating $ \dfrac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tuv} e^{-u^2/2} e^{-v^2/2}\ du\ dv $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Solving a probability problem I came across this integral:

> $$ \dfrac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tuv} e^{-u^2/2} e^{-v^2/2}\ du\ dv $$

Can you explain how to integrate this?

Comment: Try converting to polar coordinates: $u = r\cos\theta$, $v = r\sin\theta$; then integrate with respect to $r$. This leaves you a tractable integral with respect to $\theta$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. Assume $-1<t<1$. One may just integrate with respect to $u$, using the classic [gaussian result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429632/gaussian-integral),
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tuv} e^{-u^2/2} \ du=\sqrt{2\pi} \:e^{t^2v^2/2} 
$$ then with respect to $v$,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{t^2v^2/2} e^{-v^2/2} \ dv=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(1-t^2)v^2/2} \ dv=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}
$$ obtaining

> $$
> \dfrac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tuv} e^{-u^2/2} e^{-v^2/2}\ du\ dv=\frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}.
> $$

Answer (score 3):

> Lemma. Let $q(x,y)=Ax^2+2Bxy+Cy^2$ a positive definite quadratic form, associated with the symmetric matrix $M=\begin{pmatrix}A & B \\ B & C \end{pmatrix}$. We have:
>   $$ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\exp\left(-q(x,y)\right)\,dx dy = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\det M}}.$$

In our case, the quadratic form has coefficients $A=C=\frac{1}{2}$ and $B=-\frac{t}{2}$, hence:

> $$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2}-\frac{v^2}{2}+tuv\right)\,du\,dv = \color{red}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}}$$

as soon as $|t|<1$.

Comment: @YuriyS: misread, now fixed.